# After accessing the database, the rest of statements do not work

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, ado.net

I have a textBox (txtName) and a label (lblMassage).

When the Form loads user can type his name in the textbox and submit his data into the database.

My button click event is

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
  string name = txtName.Text;

  String sql = "insert into UserName values ('" + name + "')";
  SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sql, ConnectionManager.Connection());
  com.ExecuteNonQuery();

  lblMessage.Text = "Record added successfully";
  txtName.Text = "";
}

class ConnectionManager
{
    public static SqlConnection Connection()
    {
          string ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=c:\users\chathuranga\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\SansipProtoType\SansipProtoType\SansipDataBase.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
          SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
          con.Open();
          return con;
    }
}
```

when I check the database manually the value of txtName is in the table UserName which means the value user typed is added to the database successfully.

**But the following two statements won't work.**

```
lblMessage.Text = "Record added successfully";
txtName.Text = "";
```

Can anyone give me a solution?

Comment: is this your complete code..i dont see the connection open statement anywhere

Comment: Yes, something is missing.  No open, no close.  What happens when you debug through it.  Does it hit those lines or perhaps throw an error?

Comment: OK.. I added the code of Connection open and close

Comment: Do you really have a table called `UserName` with only one non default field? If not, you're most likely getting an exception which bypasses the two lines you're not seeing the result of.

Comment: Yes.. I want to store the user's name only. So the table name is  "UserName" and the field name is Name. but there's another field called "id" with an auto increment feature that acts as a primary key of the table "UserName"

Comment: In that case, the insert should be `INSERT INTO UserName (Name) VALUES('xxx')`, however, it's a good idea to parameterize like Aydin's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string name = txtName.Text;
var connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=c:\users\chathuranga\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\SansipProtoType\SansipProtoType\SansipDataBase.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
connection.Open();

var sql = "INSERT INTO UserName VALUES (@Username)";
using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", name);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
connection.Close();
connection.Dispose();
lblMessage.Text = "Record added successfully";
txtName.Text = "";
```

Updated

Comment: Soryy Sir....
Same problem again.. 

After the statement
com.ExecuteNonQuery(); other lines worn't work

Comment: I've updated the code, try that, and lets see where it takes us.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
   static SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=c:\users\chathuranga\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\SansipProtoType\SansipProtoType\SansipDataBase.mdf;Integrated Security=True";);
        string name = txtName.Text;
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO UserName VALUES (@Username)", conn);
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();


  lblMessage.Text = "Record added successfully";
  txtName.Text = "";
  conn.close();
}
```

use this code